# I want to retrieve the data from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a database using sqlitedbhelper and I am able to switch from one activity to other activity on button click.
Now I want to retrieve the data from my database on same button click and it should display on other activity.
Here is my activity code

```
    public class Assessment extends Activity 
    {
        private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/+com.comply.assessment()+/Database/"; 
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LMS_MST";
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        TextView mod_code,qst_code,question_id,question,qst_opt1,qst_opt2,qst_opt3,qst_opt4,correct_ans,user_ans;
        Cursor cursor;
        private Button start_test; 
        @SuppressWarnings("unused") 
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            start_test=(Button)findViewById(R.id.start_test);
            start_test.setOnClickListener(this);

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent1= new Intent(Assessment.this,Get_Assessment.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please I want help.

Any kind of examples would be thankful.

Answer (score 3):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database) is something that I always refer to when I am using SQLite DB in android.

Hope it helps you too!